# Assignment operators using logical operators in Python

Tags: python, logical-operators, assignment-operator

I know I can use assignment operators with arithmetic operators in Python, for example:

```
x = 0x8
x |= 0x1  # x equals 9
```

I'd like to know if this is also possible with logical operators, for example something like:

```
x = 2 > 3  # False
y = 4 > 3  # True
x or= y  # x equals True
```

Is there something similar to that `=or` operation that I can use?

Comment: Do you really need the assignments ?

Comment: @scharette yes, I am using the variables later in the code.

Comment: Technically you can use `+=`, your bools will be converted to ints but still all the truth values will be preserved: a chain of `x += False` will keep `x` equal to zero until a true value once be added so x becomes true non-zero.

Comment: @bipll true, but the logical operators are not limited to int or bool types only. I can also use `[] or {0+1j}`

Comment: If you're certain the arguments will always be booleans, `x |= y` is functionally identical to your proposed `x =or y` statement.

Comment: @Kevin I agree, but I am looking for a solution that cover all types that `and` and `or` cover.

Comment: Ok, that's a reasonable requirement. Just making sure we're all on the same page :-)

Comment: @scharette I don't think you needed to delete your answer. I just pointed out that it doesn't work for all data types. It's still useful even if it only works for integers.

Comment: @MattS What is your expected output in your example ?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I agree, but it doesn't meet the exact expected output of OP. I'll re-open.

Comment: @MattS Use ugly `x += bool([])` for those. `x += bool(y)`, or `x |= bool(y)` is now your path. :-\

Comment: @MattS I really think an edit to precisely explain what you need would be beneficial..

Comment: @bipli you shouldn't assume that either my operands nor the operation result is a boolean, in the example I presented in the comments my operands are a list and a dictionary, and the result is a dictionary

Comment: @scharette I'll maybe edit it later, but as the `and` and `or` operators are defined for many types, so should the answer be

Comment: Cute concept, but no. But anyway, it's better to do that kind of thing all in one expression if you can, since that allows you to take advantage of the short-circuiting that `and` & `or` provide.

Comment: @MattS I don't assume anything. From your question I've concluded you deal with truth values and thus calling `bool()` is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

what version of python are you in? python 3.6.5 can deal with `x = False; x |= True`, that yields `True` for x afterwards.

Comment: So just `x = True`, then? If the OP wanted to set `x` to a specific value (`True`), they wouldn't need to use any operators, would they?

Comment: well, `x|=y` works in the same way - maybe i don't quite understand the significance of his question, but it looks to me like op wants to have the equivalent to `x += 4` instead of `x = x + 4` for logical operations